# Cannot instantiate class (Selenium)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I've run into the following error."Cannot instantiate class co.edureka.tests.FBLoginTest". Below I've posted the entire error console. I'm trying to use POM (Page Obeject Model) for Selenium. I'm believe the issue has to do with me creating too many drivers... I've been digging through online resources, but haven't found anything that resolves my issue.

FBLoginPage.java

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;


public class FBLoginPage {
    

    WebDriver driver;
    
    public FBLoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver=driver;
        
    
    }
    
    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[1]/input")
    public WebElement emailTextBox;
    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="//input[@type='password'][@name='pass']") WebElement passwordTextBox;
    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="//input[@type='submit'][@value='Log In']") WebElement signinButton;
    
    // Defining all the user actions (Methods) that can be performed in the Facebook home page
    
    // This method is to set Email in the email text box
    public void setEmail(String strEmail) {
        emailTextBox.sendKeys(strEmail);
    }
    public void setPassword(String strPassword) {
        passwordTextBox.sendKeys(strPassword);
    }
    // This method is to click on Login Button
    public void clickOnLoginButton() {
        signinButton.click();
    }
}
```

FBHomePage.java

```
package co.edureka.pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;



public class FBHomePage {
    WebDriver driver;
    
    public FBHomePage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver=driver;
    }
    
@FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="//div[text()='Account Settings']") WebElement profileDropdown;
@FindBy(how=How.LINK_TEXT, using="Log Out") WebElement logoutLink;


// Defining all the user actions (Methods) that can be performed in the Facebook home page

public void clickOnProfileDropdown() {
    profileDropdown.click();
}

public void clickOnLogoutLink() {
    logoutLink.click();
}
}
```

TestBase.java

```
package co.edureka.tests;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;

public class TestBase {
    
    public static WebDriver driver;
    
@BeforeSuite
public void initialize() throws IOException{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    

    
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
}

    

@AfterSuite
public void TeardownTest()
{
    TestBase.driver.quit();
}

}
```

FBLoginTest.java

```
package co.edureka.tests;

import java.time.Duration;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import co.edureka.pages.FBHomePage;
import co.edureka.pages.FBLoginPage;



public class FBLoginTest extends TestBase {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30));


@Test
public void init() throws Exception{
    //driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
    FBLoginPage loginpage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, FBLoginPage.class);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("Facebook"));
    loginpage.setEmail("432547@gmail.com");
    loginpage.setPassword("ashish.bakshi@selenium");
    loginpage.clickOnLoginButton();
    
    FBHomePage homepage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, FBHomePage.class);
    homepage.clickOnProfileDropdown();
    homepage.clickOnLogoutLink();
}
}
```

Error Console Results

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.4.0
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class co.edureka.tests.FBLoginTest
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:30)
    at org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.instantiateUsingDefaultConstructor(InstanceCreator.java:193)
    at org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.createInstanceUsingObjectFactory(InstanceCreator.java:113)
    at org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.createInstance(InstanceCreator.java:79)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.dispense(SimpleObjectDispenser.java:25)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.dispense(GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.java:30)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:112)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:165)
    at org.testng.TestClass.getInstances(TestClass.java:122)
    at org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances(TestClass.java:102)
    at org.testng.TestClass.init(TestClass.java:94)
    at org.testng.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:59)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:463)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:339)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:292)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:223)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:33)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:66)
    at org.testng.ITestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(ITestRunnerFactory.java:55)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:659)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:173)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:107)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1300)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1276)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1125)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:79)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:483)
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:23)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input must be set
    at org.openqa.selenium.internal.Require.nonNull(Require.java:59)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.<init>(FluentWait.java:97)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:77)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:46)
    at co.edureka.tests.FBLoginTest.<init>(FBLoginTest.java:15)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
    ... 32 more
```

If anyone has any suggestions I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue you should move the `WebDriverWait` initialization to the `init` or any other method in `FBLoginTest.java` like below.

```
package co.edureka.tests;

import java.time.Duration;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import co.edureka.pages.FBHomePage;
import co.edureka.pages.FBLoginPage;


public class FBLoginTest extends TestBase {
    WebDriverWait wait;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void init() {
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
    }

    @Test
    public void testLogin() throws Exception {
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
        FBLoginPage loginpage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, FBLoginPage.class);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("Facebook"));
        loginpage.setEmail("432547@gmail.com");
        loginpage.setPassword("ashish.bakshi@selenium");
        loginpage.clickOnLoginButton();

        FBHomePage homepage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, FBHomePage.class);
        homepage.clickOnProfileDropdown();
        homepage.clickOnLogoutLink();
    }
}
```